# What's does the US hope to gain in Syria..?

Tags: armed-conflict, military, geopolitics

I know why Russia is there; to support Assad (alley of Russia) but what can the US gain from this? They are arming rebels (as if that ever worked) most likely ISIS in Syria to fight Assad and are also fighting ISIS in Iraq. What is their goal?

Comment: cynical answer: The US and Russia have always loved proxy wars with each other.

Comment: For Russia, it's about keeping Assad in power and the US is arming the same rebels they are fighting in Iraq!

Comment: @Noah The situation in Syria is more complex than that. There are a couple of Syrian rebel factions with different goals and ideologies, there is ISIS and the Kurds in the north are also mixing in. They are *all* fighting for dominance in Syria. There are not just two sides in that war, there is about half a dozen.